# why transform xml component in logic app doesn't show XML as output

Tags: azure-logic-apps, workflow-definition-language

Why transform XML component in logic app doesn't show XML as output?
When I create my logic app for receiving EDI 850 x12 message.
I use decode x12 component in the logic app workflow then I used transform XML. There I gave input as XML with the Workflow definition language "@xml(base64ToBinary(item()?['Payload']))" for this I get output as

[image]

But I need output as XML. Please help me fix this issue.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what the name of your mapping action is, but if what you need is the output XML as a string, then try this: 
`"@base64ToString(body('<<Your_Mapping_Action>>')?['$content'])"`

As you could see, XML **objects** in Logic Apps are always base64 encoded.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

i used compose component to pass output of transform XML using "@join(outputs('Compose'),';')" and i added Parse JSON component in logic app workflow with schema

{"properties": {"?xml":{"properties":{"@@encoding":{"type": "string"},           "@@version":{"type": "string"}},"type": "object"},"ns0:Root":{"properties":{              "@@xmlns:ns0":{"type": "string"},"PODate":{"type": "string"},"PONumber": {"type": "string"},"RetailerID":{"type": "string"}},"type": "object"}},"type":"object"}

There my SCHEMA wasn't correct and i added above schema in parse JSON to get output to insert row. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can now use string().  String() will convert the binary output to a string.

So your expression would be:

```
string(item()?['Payload'])
```